# Determine for what values of m the function is a solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was working through some differential equations and came across this problem.

Determine for which values of $m$ the function $\phi(x)=e^{mx}$ is a solution to the given equation.

A) $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+5y=0$

B) $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+3\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

For part A I received the solution of $m = -1$ and $m = -5$, which I am confident in my answer. For B I am a little unsure if I did the problem correctly.

WORK: $\phi(x)=e^{mx};\phi'(x)=me^{mx};\phi''(x)=m^2e^{mx};\phi'''(x)=m^3e^{mx}$(1)

Substitution of (1) into part B: $m^3e^{mx}
+3m^2e^{mx}+2me^{mx}=0$..............(2)

$me^{mx}(m^2e^{mx}
+3me^{mx}+2)=0$ ..............................................................(3)

Equating: $me^{mx}=0$ (4) and $m^2e^{mx}
+3me^{mx}+2=0$........................... (5)

Solving (4): $me^{mx}=0$, $m=0$

Solving (5): $m^2e^{mx}
+3me^{mx}+2=0$

$m^2e^{mx}
+3me^{mx}=-2$..................................................................................(6)

$e^{mx}(m^2+3m)=-2$......................................................................................(7)

$e^{mx} = -2$ Has no solution and the solution to $m^2+3m=-2$ after completing the sqare is $m=-1$ and $m=-2$.

So overall my solution to B are $m=0,-1,-2$

Does this seem correct?

Comment: m cannot be zero. Check by putting 0 in the auxillary equation.

Comment: Line 3 is wrong. You factored incorrectly.

Comment: Moreover, your reasoning for line 7 and following is a common error. From $ab=-2$ it certainly doesn't follow that either $a$ or $b$ is $-2$.

Comment: $me^{mx}(m^2
+3m+2)=0$ is the proper factoring of line 3. But I also end up with $m=-1,-2$ since $(m+2)(m+1)=0$ I am not sure what I am currently doing wrong.